# Deno. connect: invalid peer certificate: UnknownIssuer

Tags: deno

Deno v.1.38.0. JavaScript, Visual Studio Code v.1.84.2, Mac M1.

```
import * as mod from "https://deno.land/std@0.206.0/fs/ensure_dir.ts";
```

I get the error:

> error: Import 'https://deno.land/std@0.206.0/fs/ensure_dir.ts' failed:
> error sending request for url
> (https://deno.land/std@0.206.0/fs/ensure_dir.ts): error trying to
> connect: invalid peer certificate: UnknownIssuer.

[Deno](https://deno.com) provides some useful modules are written on TypeScript. For example, it is possible to check directory existing through [this](https://deno.land/std@0.206.0/fs/exists.ts?s=existsSync) module. I want to use this module in my JavaScript code but I get this error. How can I solve it?

Comment: You can use those modules just the same from a JavaScript program.

Comment: @AKX I tried it but I get the error: `error: Import 'https://deno.land/std@0.206.0/fs/ensure_dir.ts' failed: error sending request for url (https://deno.land/std@0.206.0/fs/ensure_dir.ts): error trying to connect: invalid peer certificate: UnknownIssuer`. Visual Studio Code, Mac M1.

Comment: That's related to your network connection.

Comment: "*error trying to connect: invalid peer certificate: UnknownIssuer.*" does not have anything to do with JS vs TS